# auto suggest/autocomplete for multiple comboBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Anyone know how can I make autocomplete/auto suggest for multiple comboBox. Lets say I have 3 comboBox, I want each of them have autocomplete and autosuggest base in the DATABASE. Also in my MSAccess database I have 3 fields. These fields are for the three comboBox.

So here's my code for the autocomplete for comboBox1 = Firstname, comboBox2 = lastname, comboBox3 = Country. It does work but I want to add the 2 comboBox.

```
con2.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = con2;
cmd.CommandText = "select FirstName from Records";
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
AutoCompleteStringCollection mycollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

while (reader.Read())
{
   mycollection.Add(reader.GetString(0));
}

comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycollection;
con2.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to populate all your comboxes from one method, if you provide the comboboxes as parameters.

Here is a implementation of that suggestion.

```
// using System.Data;

void AddAutoComplete(IDbConnection con2, string sql, params ComboBox[] combos) 
{
    // Have an array of colections, element for each combo
    var mycollections = new AutoCompleteStringCollection[combos.Length];
 
    // initialize each array element
    for(var x=0; x < combos.Length;x++) {
        mycollections[x] = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    }
    
    // do the work
    using(var cmd = con2.CreateCommand())
    {
        con2.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con2;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();      

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // iterate by index for each combo
            for(var i=0; i< combos.Length; i++) 
            {
                // add each field to each AutoComplete
                mycollections[i].Add(reader.GetString(i));
            }
        }
        con2.Close();
    }

    // set the autocompletion for each combo from the collections
    for(var x=0; x < combos.Length;x++) {
        combos[x].AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycollections[x];
    }    
}
```

Notice how I generalized the creation of the database command based of the database connection so this method can be used for any database, not just OleDb ones. See [`DbConnection.CreateCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection.createcommand?view=netframework-4.0) for how that works.

This is how you would use it:

```
var sql = "select FirstName,Lastname,Country from Records";
AddAutoComplete(con2, sql, cmb1, cmb2, cmb2);
```